# R shiny modify a specific element in a reactive table

Tags: r, shiny

I have a small shiny app that is designed to read in from a data set, and then calculate the average time per element, grouped by category.  My dataset is a more complicated version of:

```
item time category
apple 13 cat1
bobcat 6 cat2
cement 15 cat1
doomsday 15 cat1
elephant 7 cat2
```

after reading in that file, I generate a table describing the percent of total time attributed to each category.  This part is working beautifully.

> category | PercentTime
>
> cat1 | 76.79
>
> cat2 | 23.21

To complicate things a bit, I have an input field where the user can estimate some percentage of time that they spend on a specific category--intended to capture an estimate on time that is not represented in the data set.  Then, I generate a second table which recalculates what those percentages of time allocated to each category would be, *adjusted for the percentage of time that is estimated to be part of that category*. If we input a value of 50% of time going towards `cat2` that was not represented in the data, I would expect the table to be modified to:

> category | PercentTime
>
> cat1 | 38.39
>
> cat2 | 61.61

*where 61.61 = 11.61 + 50*

I am presently able to generate a table comprised of the correct percentages of time in each category **excluding** the addition of the user input percentage.  So what I am getting adds up to less than 100%:

> category | PercentTime
>
> cat1 | 38.39
>
> cat2 | 11.61

I'd like to tweak that one specific PercentTime element for `cat2` by adding the input value to the calculated percent time, so it's the correct number (61.61).

Shiny app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'inputtext'),
    numericInput('UnknownPercent', 'labeltext', 50)),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("tab1", 
                         tableOutput("data_only"),
                         tableOutput("data_inc_unknown_percent"))
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  G2T <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    
    isolate({ 
      G2T_raw <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })
    G2T_raw
  })
  
  TotalTime <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    
    isolate({ 
      TotalTime <- G2T() %>%
        summarise(TotalTime = sum(time))
      })
    TotalTime
  })
  
  CatTable <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    
    isolate({ 
      TotalTime <- G2T() %>%
        summarise(TotalTime = sum(time))
      CatTable <- G2T() %>%
        group_by(category) %>%
        summarise(PercentTime = sum(time) / TotalTime * 100)
    })
    CatTable
  })
  
  CatTablePlus <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    
    isolate({ 
      TotalTime <- G2T() %>%
        summarise(TotalTime = sum(time))
      CatTablePlus <- G2T() %>%
        group_by(category) %>%
        summarise(PercentTime = ((sum(time) / TotalTime()) * (100 - input$UnknownPercent[1])))
      CatTablePlus <- as.data.frame(CatTablePlus)
    })
    CatTablePlus
  })
  
  
  
  output$data_only <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1)
    CatTable()  
  }) 
  
  output$data_inc_unknown_percent <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1) 
    CatTablePlus()
  }) 
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add my user input percentage to that [category = cat2, time] element of my table.  I have tried:

- Moving the table manipulation logic to different places, either the renderTable section, or keeping it in the reactive section
- Treating my generated table as something with modifiable elements, using a command like  `CatTablePlus[CatTablePlus$category == "cat1", "PercentTime"] <- CatTablePlus[CatTablePlus$category == "cat1", "PercentTime"] + input$UnknownPercent[1]`.  Depending on how I approach this, I either perform the operation of adding UnknownPercent[1] to all of the PercentTime elements, or get errors like `Error: 'row.names' should specify one of the variables` in my output.
- Creating new local variables in the place of the reactive table objects
- Coercing my reactive table into different types such as data.frame

How can I adjust a single element in a Shiny renderTable object, reactively, as a user adjusts a numericInput value?

Comment: Just a quick check, Do you have only two categories in your data also?

Comment: I have five categories in the actual data set, and I'm modifying 2 of those 5 ultimately.

Comment: Then the below code would work well for the shiny part but the logic for the 5 category case must be updated for the second table. btw, did you try the code?

Comment: Yes I did.  Runs like a dream :) . This has been maddening me for weeks, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a couple of changes with your code and also have commented out some part of yours.

1. Used `eventReactive` to track the input `numericInput` change and render dataframe accordingly.
2. Assuming that you would have only two categories, hard-coded the percentage shifting logic.

Updated Code:

```
    library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'inputtext'),
    numericInput('UnknownPercent', 'labeltext', 50)),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("tab1", 
                         tableOutput("data_only"),
                         tableOutput("data_inc_unknown_percent"))
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

  G2T <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

    isolate({ 
      G2T_raw <<- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })
    G2T_raw
  })

  TotalTime <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

    isolate({ 
      TotalTime <- G2T() %>%
        summarise(TotalTime = sum(time))
    })
    TotalTime
  })

  CatTable <- reactive({
    if(input$file1 == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

    isolate({  
      CatTable <- G2T() %>% group_by(category) %>%
        summarise(time = sum(time)) %>% ungroup(category) %>% mutate(time = (time / sum(time))*100)
    })
    CatTable
  })

  CatTablePlus <- eventReactive(input$UnknownPercent,{ 


     # TotalTime <-  G2T() %>%
      #  summarise(TotalTime = sum(time))

      # G2T() %>%
      #  group_by(category) %>%
       # summarise(PercentTime = ((sum(time) / TotalTime) * (100 - input$UnknownPercent[1])))

    unknownpct_table <- CatTable() 

    #unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat2'] <- 100 -  unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat1']

    unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat1'] <- unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat1'] -  unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat1'] * (input$UnknownPercent[1] /100)
    unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat2'] <- 100 -  unknownpct_table$time[unknownpct_table$category == 'cat1']

    unknownpct_table

  })



  output$data_only <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1)
    CatTable()
  }) 

  output$data_inc_unknown_percent <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1) 
    CatTablePlus()
  }) 
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Yes!! This is perfect and exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  I'm pretty sure I can extend it to hard code to my five categories.  Won't be pretty, but it'll work :)

Comment: Glad to know that!